# JavaScript Web Worker close() not working

Tags: javascript, web-worker

My web worker calls close() repeatedly but doesn't stop. Here is the worker's script:

```
self.onmessage = function (e) {
    close();
    for (c in e.data) {
        postMessage(e.data[c]);
        close();
    }
}
```

The for loop executes without issue. Can someone explain why?

Comment: How is worker initiated ?

Comment: `close();` doesn’t seem to work in the `message` callback function. Try `return;`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/ioflPsxDpeilQQyG4YMN?p=preview

Comment: Worker is initiated in javascript on client: var worker = new Worker('Scripts/workerScript.js');      Seems to be that close doesn't terminate the method (as return would (thanks Xufox)), but instead close disables the worker - no longer able to worker.postMessage().

Answer (score 2):

It will simply close the worker from that point forward, but the current onmessage event will continue to be handled by this function i.e. the for loop will be executed. You would need to employ some logic in the worker that would update a boolean value and you would then check that boolean prior to executing the for loop.

If you don't want the for loop to execute, then you'd need to do something like this instead:

```
self.onmessage = function(e) {
    const valid = <SOME BOOLEAN LOGIC HERE>;
    if (valid) {
        for (c in e.data) {
            postMessage(e.data[c]);
        }
    } else {
        close();
    }
}
```